# how to wrap jasmine test suit into a function expression

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a couple of test cases which are applicable for both mobile and tablet devices, i want to wrap the test cases into function expression and then call the function for mobile and tablet each

```
describe('When the user is on mobile' , function() {
beforeAll(function() {
//I am setting the viewport size here (mobile)
});

describe('test case 1' function() {    
beforeAll( function() {
//test case that runs for mobile
});

it('test case 2' function() {
expect(); //test case that runs for mobile
});
});
});

describe('When the user is on  tablet' , function() {
beforeAll(function() {
//I am setting the viewport size here (tablet
});

describe('test case 1' function() {    
beforeAll( function() {
//test case that runs for tablet
});

it('test case 2' function() {
expect(); //test case that runs for tablet
});
});
});

describe('When the user is on mobile or tablet' , function() {
beforeAll(function() {
//I am setting the viewport size here (mobile or tablet
});

describe('test case 1' function() {    // can i wrap this describe into a function expression and call it inside first describe for mobile and tablet 
beforeAll( function() {
//test case that runs for mobile and tablet
});

it('test case 2' function() {
expect(); //test case that runs for mobile and tablet
});
});
});
```

I want to reduce the code replication by converting the test suite into a function expression , is there any possible way?

Comment: I think you are trying js way with .spec where you want to write test case in the function and call it multiple times but haven't came across such things in jasmine however you can try wrapping it in a better way from ur above example

Comment: check this article for shared unit test cases: https://juristr.com/blog/2014/10/avoid-test-code-duplication-jasmine/